# Why does a variable work, but not a list for opening a workbook using xlrd in python?

Tags: python, xlsx, xlrd

I'm extremely new to python so I appreciate any help. I've been attacking this from every angle I can imagine for the last 4 days in hopes I could figure it out myself, but I'm stumped.

I'm trying to create a list of files from a specific directory with the extension .xlsx. Then I want to take those file names from the list and run some function, passing the discovered file name into the function, and iterating it with each file name. I've tried to do this in multiple ways, but for some reason I it won't accept the file names.

```
import os
import xlrd

mypath = "some path to files"
fileslist = []

def find_files():
    for file in os.listdir(mypath):
        if file.endswith(".xlsx")
            fileslist.append(file)

def other_function():    
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(fileslist)
```

I can print fileslist and show that it's populated with the correct info. I've done this in both the main part of the script and also within the other_function() area. I also tried testing out naming a variable fileslist with a valid file name in the directory, let's say "file1.xlsx" and that works. Once I input it into a list, even if the only entry in the list is "file1.xlsx" I get the following error

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(fileslist)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 110, in open_workbook
    filename = os.path.expanduser(filename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 254, in expanduser
    if not path.startswith('~'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: A list of files is not the same thing as a file.

Comment: What's missing in your code is the "*iterating it with each file name*" part. There is no iteration.

Comment: @melpomene In interest of keeping the post as short as I could I didn't enter that part of the code. I was more interested in finding out why I was getting the specific error, as that is where my script would break down, and no iteration could happen as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd` is looking for a file path to open. A list (of files) is 1) not a filepath, but multiple file paths and 2) not a string, which is the specific error you're getting. A string (which is a Python object) has a method `.startswith` which allows `xlrd` to check if the first part of the filepath (you're supposed to give `open_workbook`) is a `~` or not. xlrd probably did this because that would affect where it looks for the file.

`xlrd.open_workbook` is essentially trying to double click on the filepath you send it, you are (essentially) trying to click on all of the files in your list at the same time, which might be possible if you could have X different computer mice with a hand for each, but isn't really possible the way computers are typically built.

If you want to make a dictionary of the different workbooks you have, but opened with xlrd you can use this:

```
xlrd_wbs = dict()
for my_file in filelist:
    xlrd_wbs[my_file] = xlrd.open_workbook(my_file)
```

and then access the different files with:

`xlrd_wbs[whatever_file_path_you_used]`

I would use a dictionary here because it allows you to access which file you want more reliably, if you just want a list though, you can do this:

```
xlrd_wbs = []
for my_file in filelist:
    xlrd_wbs.append(xlrd.open_workbook(my_file))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would that mean that if the directory to the file had only 1 file with a .xlsx extension, and I forced the script to output as a string using str() it would then have the required .startswith method? Not that I'm planning to use that solution, I'm just trying to understand this more clearly to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: you can try calling `str` on a list, it won't give you a legit filepath (`str(['a'])` yields `"['a']"`. you could access the single file by indexing into your list, e.g. `my_files[0]` but that is essentially what the above examples do, without limiting you to the first file you find with `find_files()`.

Comment: thanks. Now I see why another method I tried only returned one result from the function. I don't have time now but I'm going to try your solution later on when I have time.